# Few extremely large values when using RDTSCP in C

Tags: c, linux, time, scheduling

I am using the following function to measure clock cycles taken by a simple operation:

```
uint64_t rdtscp(void) {
  uint32_t lo, hi;
  __asm__ volatile ("rdtscp"
      : /* outputs */ "=a" (lo), "=d" (hi)
      : /* no inputs */
      : /* clobbers */ "%rcx");
  return (uint64_t)lo | (((uint64_t)hi) << 32);
}
```

To avoid taking into account possible delay due to interrupts, I parsed /proc/interrupts file in the read_intr() function and considered the value only if there were no new interrupts on CPU 0.

These functions are used to measure the cycles taken by the operation in a loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < 256; j++)
    {
        rnd1 = rand() % 256;

        intr1 = read_intr();
        start = rdtscp();
        rnd1 + 1;  // Operation
        end = rdtscp();
        intr2 = read_intr();

        if (intr1 == intr2)
        {
            printf("%lu\n", end - start);
            fflush(stdout);
        }
    }
}
```

I then ran the above program using:

```
$ sudo schedtool -F -p 99 -e taskset 0x1 ./a.out > output
```

That is, the program is scheduled using SCHED_FIFO with 99 priority and forced to run on CPU 0.

I analyzed the output counter values to obtain the following statistical parameters about the execution cycles taken:

```
Mean = 36.49
Median = 33
```

However, when the output is sorted in descending order the first few values are:

```
32593
29081
28878
1113
1065
612
```

What is the reason for these (very few) extremely high counter readings even after interrupts are being considered? Also, given that the first three sorted readings are much higher than the following three (shown), could this be because of different reasons?

Edit: Based on gudok's comment, I turned off hyper-threading and also automatic power management from the BIOS settings, but still find a discrepancy as mentioned below.

Comment: Is hyper-threading enabled?

Comment: I re-tried by disabling hyper-threading, and while this indeed made a difference for the tiny operation mentioned above, when I executed a different, slightly more complex instruction (a function call) a similar pattern to the one above occurs. Any possible reasons for this? Thanks.

Comment: `/proc/interrupts file in the read_intr() function` So: read_intr() function contains a system call (read()) which can be blocked, for instance by a lock. It could even be put on the runnable queue.

Comment: Although it may be blocked for reading, that does not effect the time stamp because the start and end values are obtained in between the read_intr() operations. If I understand correctly, it would matter if the read_intr() were instead placed in between the rdtscp() calls, which is not the case?

Comment: @wildplasser: Even if put on the runnable queue, it would still be picked for execution first given that it is running with maximum SCHED_FIFO priority, and as mentioned in my previous comment, this will not change the time(cycle) measurements, right?

Comment: And what about a (spin)lock in the read() from the /proc/ pseudo filesystem?

Comment: I still do not see how a (spin)lock would delay the counted cycles. Even if the task is waiting on the lock to be released due to read(), it will re-start execution and only then measure the rdtscp value for start (and end), so the delay due to locking should not factor into the measurement. Could you please explain, and perhaps also mention how to circumvent it? Apologies if I am missing something rather obvious...